# vim select text

Tags: vim

I have a file which looks like this:

```
1 148 1  4
2 333 1  3
3 534 2  3
4 772 g  7
5 921 p  2
```

I want to yank text from line 1 to 5 and from column 1 to 7:

```
1 148 1  
2 333 1  
3 534 2  
4 772 g  
5 921 p
```

can I do that from the vim command-line? If I type

```
:1,5ya a
```

the entire line is yanked into register "a" and I want just certain columns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute *any* command on the command line, here with the help of `:normal`:

```
:execute "normal! 1G^\<C-v>6l5j\"ay"
```

This builds a *blockwise selection*, then yanks it to register a. The `:execute` is used so that the `\<C-v>` notation can be used instead of literally inserting it. It also allows you to replace the hard-coded limits with variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in a simple way from the vim command line.  `:y` is a **linewise** command - it only affects whole lines.  What you're looking for is considered **blockwise**.  The blockwise commands involve Visual mode.  So the best you can do is:

1. CTRL-V to start visual mode.
2. Highlight the text you want.
3. `"ay` to yank the highlighted text into register `a`.

Comment: Regarding 2: `6l4j` should do it (assuming you're on the top left corner of the block).

Answer (score 0):

Not really general, but this should work:

```
:1,5y|put|-4,.s/\(.\{7\}\).*/\1/|-4,.d a
```

Yank 5 lines, put (copy) them, delete everything after the desired columns, delete them into the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, more suitable for a script:

```
:let @a = join(map(getline(1, 5), 'matchstr(v:val, ".*\\%<9v")'), "\n")
```

It retrieves the lines as a List (`getline()`), then matches the first 7 virtual columns through the special `/\%<v` regular expression atom, and assigns that (`join()`ed as a string) to the register `@a`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do

## <kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>2w</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

and be done (start from the top of the document with <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>)

Of course, if you wanted it in register *a*, add `"a`:

### <kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>2w</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>